# Python: A complete list of modules

Tags: python, module

How do I get a list of all python modules available?

I don't want modules of modules. Just a basic list of all modules available in `sys.path`.

`help('modules')` is not the solution, because I want it available as a variable and it imports those modules, which has side effects.

**Edit**: With side effects I mean libraries like kivy of http://kivy.org/, which make use of the fact, that code is executed once you import it.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate question, since `pkgutil` wasn't even mentioned in the other thread and there's a clear limitation here: **No side effects!**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[pkgutil](http://docs.python.org/library/pkgutil.html) - Utilities to support packages

this will yield a tuple for all submodules on sys.path:

```
pkgutil.iter_modules()
```

to see what's loaded, look at:

```
sys.modules
```

> "This is a dictionary that maps module names to modules which have
>   already been loaded"

- http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.modules

a list of loaded modules:

```
sys.modules.keys()
```

Comment: "which have already been loaded". OP wants all loadable modules.

Comment: @jsbueno.  how does pkgutil *not* answer this?  afaict, it gives what he asks: "list of all modules available in sys.path".

Comment: @jsbueno pkgutil.iter_modules() "Yields (module_loader, name, ispkg) for all submodules on path, or, if path is None, all top-level modules on sys.path."  That is what he asked.

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg: I stand corrected. Sorry for the annoyance.

Comment: i think executing `pkgutil.iter_modules()` loads all modules to memory.

Answer (score 5):

Use the external script "pydoc" that comes along with a Python install:
from the command shell, type:

```
$ pydoc modules
```

Pydoc can be used from within Python as well, one way of having it walk everything available is:

```
all_mod = []
pydoc.ModuleScanner().run(callback=(lambda *a: all_mod.append(a[1])), onerror=lambda *a:None)
print all_mod
```

Comment: A good idea, but it imports those modules (can have side effects if you have things like `kivy` installed.

Comment: What pydoc does is manually check for all available files and then import them - if you don't want the import part, I think you will have to look at pydoc code and copy from it to see all available modules (including those in zip files and eggs).